# Where can I find the "History of Visual Studio" video shown at the VS 2010 Launch?

Tags: visual-studio, video, history

Kind of a weird question to ask on SO, but it is programming related, so hear me out!

I've been looking for a few months (with no results) for a video shown at a local Visual Studio 2010 launch event. The video was a high-production-value piece covering the history of Visual Studio from the early days up to the present. It was maybe 10 minutes long and featured blurbs from ScottGu and other product team members at Microsoft. Does anybody know if Microsoft posted this to Channel 9 or somewhere else? I don't even remember the actual title of the video, so I've had some trouble tracking it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be the page where all parts are visible

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/VisualStudioDocumentary/

Answer (score 3):

[Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/) is where such things would normally be found, together with much other Microsoft footage.

[Here](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/VisualStudioDocumentary/The-Visual-Studio-Documentary-Part-One/) is part one, and [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/VisualStudioDocumentary/The-Visual-Studio-Documentary-Part-Two/) is part two.

Answer (score 2):

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/VisualStudioDocumentary/The-Visual-Studio-Documentary-Part-One/